# JPA Many to Many trouble

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, h2

I have been reading and watching tons of tutorials and just can't seem to get the many to many relationship to work.  I have built a new project to simplify the project down to one many to many relationship.  Please take a look at the code below and lend some suggestions as to why this fails.  Currently I get a null pointer at the *keywd.getMaterialRecordList().add(record); line.  If I comment this out then I get the same null pointer on the next .get....add();.  If it matters I have abandoned Derby and moved to an H2 database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MATERIAL_RECORD")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "MaterialRecord.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MaterialRecord m")})
public class MaterialRecord implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "SDS_NUMBER")
private Integer sdsNumber;
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
private String productName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "materialRecordList")
private List<Keywords> keywordsList;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KEYWORDS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Keywords.findAll", query = "SELECT k FROM Keywords k")})
public class Keywords implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "KEY_ID")
private Integer keyId;
@Column(name = "KEYWORD_NAME")
private String keywordName;
@JoinTable(name = "KEYWORD_LOOKUP", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "KEY_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "SDS_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "SDS_NUMBER")})
@ManyToMany
private List<MaterialRecord> materialRecordList;
```

---

```
public class JpaTest {
public static void main (String [] args){
   MaterialRecord record = new MaterialRecord();
   record.setProductName("oofbar");

   Keywords keywd = new Keywords();
   keywd.setKeywordName("testing");

   Keywords keywd2 = new Keywords();
   keywd2.setKeywordName("testing2");

   record.getKeywordsList().add(keywd);
   record.getKeywordsList().add(keywd2);

   keywd.getMaterialRecordList().add(record);
   keywd2.getMaterialRecordList().add(record);

   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaApplication26PU");

   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
   tx.begin();
   em.persist(record);
   em.persist(keywd);
   em.persist(keywd2);
   tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here are my thoughts.

To avoid the null pointer exception as the entity is not retrieved from the persistence context the Collection in this case the list has not been initialized, so use this.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "materialRecordList")
private List<Keywords> keywordsList = new ArrayList<Keywords>();
```

Or if you dont want to use that approach use setter method to create and set the list before try to fill it. That will avoid null pointer exceptions and your example should work. =)

This only is needed as you are creating your own entity from scratch, If you use find that list will be filled and created automatically.

Comment: This was definitely the issue causing the null pointer.  I had to add a similar entry to the MaterialRecord list also in the other class thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with relation. ManyToMany  relation need to be with primary keys of two table.

try this :

```
@JoinTable(name = "KEYWORD_LOOKUP", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "KEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "KEY_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "SDS_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
@ManyToMany
private List<MaterialRecord> materialRecordList;
```

update me if you still get some problem.

Comment: I think you have the reason the mapping is incorrect, but null pointer are not caused by that, that error will appears once java reach the line Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory, so at this point user is not aware of that but it should be fixed also XD

Comment: As you suspected, I do get another exception at the createEntityManagerFactory line.  I made the change of referencedColumnName to "ID" which is definitely the primary key.  I however am now getting a persistence exception for no persistence provider for the entity manager named JavaApplication26PU.  The persistence unit does exist and it is in the package META-INF.  Any clues as to why it may be throwing that exception?  Thanks again for your help guys, it is much appreciated!!!!

Comment: So the persistence exception was caused by me not importing the correct library for both the persistence provider (eclipselink) as well as the H2 driver.

Comment: After importing the libraries I received another error which seemed to be pointing to a mismatch with the "ID" that I changed per your suggestion.  I tried changing it back to "SDS_NUMBER" and it commits the record properly.  I assume this works because I had created the database from SQL script and already had the foreign keys generated linking the SDS_NUMBER COLUMNS.  I am new to this so correct me please if my logic isn't sound.  Good news is that it is working now so THANK YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE!

Comment: yes, if you have created schema using sql script then you need to follow the same structure as in schema.